# How do I save an Machine Learning ensemble of models on my PC?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, saving-data

I'm using Google Colab, and my runtime keeps disconnecting. Rather than training it again and again, I thought I'd store it in a PC, somehow. So that if I have to demonstrate it, I can just load that file and use .predict.
I need to save it to my PC so that I can run it with a simple .load() function if something disconnects on the platform I'm using.

Comment: You have not mentioned your tools, shown your code, or talked about what you've tried. Please update your question so we know how best to answer it.

Comment: @erip My question was generic; the only specificity was out of the fact that I’m using Colab. The question’s been answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python you can use pickling to save as an object

```
import pickle
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
# load the model from disk
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.score(X_test, Y_test)
print(result)
```

Comment: Does it save this to my computer, though? Can you elaborate on what happens in the .dumps() line?

Comment: it coverts your training model into object and saves on your computer. (Read about serialization and deserialization or (pickling and unpickling) ) you will get an idea.